# How do you generate Java method signatures that throw exceptions in JRuby? (i.e. to implement interfaces such as org.quartz.Job)

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

Given the following code:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'org.quartz.*'

class RubyTestJob
    java_implements Java::org.quartz.Job

    java_signature 'void execute(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws org.quartz.JobExecutionException'
    def execute( context )
        puts "bar"
    end
end
```

running

```
jrubyc -c lib/quartz-all-2.1.1.jar --javac lib/rubytestjob.rb
```

produces an abstract class, because the "throws org.quartz.JobExecutionException" seems to be ignored when generating the execute method.

Is there a way to do this in JRuby?

Comment: @rlb.usa What university did you go to where they had JRuby/Java interop coursework?